# Getting 302 redirect issue by adding a product to wishlist

Tags: redirect, wishlist

This is the url for the wishlist:

`<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($item) ?>`

It works. It puts the product to the wishlist. But instead of redirecting me to the wishlist list. It shows me that "**The page isn't redirecting properly**" and the firebug displays the 302 error message. What should I check/change to make this work ?

Comment: any idea  or suggestion ?

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
```

Comment: it is an image button. so I don't need the add to wishlist text. Just for curiosity i change it as you suggested, but i still getting the 302

Comment: Can you please share your url

Comment: Yes sure. This is the link: http://latesthoes.mediaswitch.ro/. If you are not logged in it redirects you to the login page, which is fine, but after when you add a product it doesnt redirect you to the wishlist list .  but it shows you this message: The page isn't redirecting properly